# How to link an unknown library

Tags: c++

For example I am trying to use GLFW3 and it throws the following error at me

> x11_init.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `XIQueryVersion'.

I only know that it has something to do with X11 but how do I know which library I have to link? How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: I would type `XIQueryVersion` in Google.

Comment: Forums, documentation, Google, Wiki ;)

Comment: Guess what is the first google result for this question now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `nm` to list the symbols defined in the system libraries in order to find which one contains your missing symbol :

```
find /usr/lib/ -type f -name \*.a \
  -exec nm -gAC --defined-only {} 2> /dev/null \; \
    | grep \ XIQueryVersion
```

Which outputs :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.a:XIQueryVersion.o:00000110 T XIQueryVersion
```

Then you know you have to link `libXi.a`, of course you can adjust the library path and symbol name, and that would only work if you already have the right library in your system.

Answer (score 5):

I would proceed in this order:

1. look in the **X11 doc** to see if they tell you which lib to link to obtain this function
2. look on the **web** if you can find a reference to this lib
3. use `nm` on the X11 libs to see which one contains this reference

(shhhhhh... it's `libxi`)

Comment: Okay now I found it too. I only thought there would be a faster way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar linking errors. My error was saying:

```
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16d3): undefined reference to `XIQueryVersion'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `createWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x6de): undefined reference to `XISelectEvents'
```

But since I wanted **Cmake linking flags** for the required linking libs, it took me a while to do so.  Required external libs, to compile glfw based program, are:

```
Requires.private:  x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm gl
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685903/glfw3-undefined-reference-to-xrr) thread shows how to find these libs needed to compile glfw based program.

Since, I spent 2-3 hours looking for Cmake linking flags for the above additional linking libs. I think it's worth mentioning here to help others.

Mainly for the error I have mentioned above, I just needed a cmake linking flag for `xi` only, but for completeness sake I am mentioning for all of them, i.e. `x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm`. Here is the snippet from my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
include_directories(
    ./src
    ${X11_xf86vmode_INCLUDE_PATH}
    ${X11_Xrandr_INCLUDE_PATH}
    ${X11_Xinput_INCLUDE_PATH}
)

    target_link_libraries(
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        ${X11_LIBRARIES}
        ${X11_Xxf86vm_LIB}
        ${X11_Xrandr_LIB}
        ${X11_Xinput_LIB}
    )
```

I extracted these flags from this [link](https://github.com/fogleman/Craft/blob/master/deps/glfw/CMakeLists.txt).
Hope, it will save time for others. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error when I tried to build the OpenGL tutorial code. I fix it by uninstall the `libxi-dev` package.

I first clean the build directory by

```
cd build/
rm -r ./*
```

And then remove the libxi-dev package by

```
sudo apt-get remove libxi-dev
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And rebuild the project by

```
cd build/
cmake .. # My ogl directory
make all
```

And then succeed. (Actually I don't know what is the root cause, but it works for me.)