# GLFW3 - Undefined reference to XRR

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am trying to compile a very simple [OpenGL program](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html) that uses GLFW3. Despite linking everything I deem necessary, I'm getting a plethora of undefined references.

```
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_gamma.c.o): In function `_glfwInitGammaRamp':
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcGammaSize'
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_gamma.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp':
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcGammaSize'
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcGamma'
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `XRRFreeGamma'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_gamma.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp':
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `XRRAllocGamma'
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x303): undefined reference to `XRRSetCrtcGamma'
x11_gamma.c:(.text+0x30f): undefined reference to `XRRFreeGamma'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1a67): undefined reference to `XRRQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1a91): undefined reference to `XRRQueryVersion'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b25): undefined reference to `XIQueryVersion'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwSetVideoMode':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `XRRSetCrtcConfig'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x3e8): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x3f4): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwRestoreVideoMode':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x446): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x46b): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4e0): undefined reference to `XRRSetCrtcConfig'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4ec): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x4f8): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetMonitors':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x55a): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x577): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputPrimary'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x5cf): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x5ea): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x659): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x676): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x682): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x703): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x70f): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x733): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x8a2): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x8c7): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x8ff): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x90b): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetVideoModes':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x9ad): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x9cf): undefined reference to `XRRGetOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `XRRFreeOutputInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xb50): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetVideoMode':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xc28): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenResources'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xc4d): undefined reference to `XRRGetCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xca2): undefined reference to `XRRFreeCrtcInfo'
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0xcae): undefined reference to `XRRFreeScreenResources'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `createWindow':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x666): undefined reference to `XISelectEvents'
x11_window.c:(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to `XRRSelectInput'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `processEvent':
x11_window.c:(.text+0x1711): undefined reference to `XRRUpdateConfiguration'
```

My linked CMake flags:

```
-I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3  -lGLU -lGL -lGLEW
```

Should I be linking anything else?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself while writing the question.

I was misled into believing that I was linking everything necessary because of the output of

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags --print-requires glfw3
```

which was

```
-I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3
```

The `--print-requires` flag was having no impact at all on the output, which seemed odd. I searched and printed the corresponding `.pc` file.

```
sudo find / | grep "glfw3\.pc"
cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
```

There I found this.

```
Requires.private:  x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm gl
```

Which indicates which libraries are required for static linking. I added their correponding flags to CMake and it worked. My mistake was that I missed the `--print-requires-private` flag when executing pkg-config.

I hope this helps someone save some time.

Comment: +1 for explaining how you solved your problem :D I realize I'm excavating this thread, but the link below explains installating GLFW from the source perfectly. It saved me quite some time and messiness:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project

Comment: I am under Ubuntu 14.04 and had to add theses libraries: `X11 Xrandr Xi Xxf86vm Xcursor Xinerama`