# GLFW3 failing to link properly with Netbeans 8.1

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, glfw, netbeans-8.1

I have looked at some 20 different pages on stackoverflow or otherwise, and none of them have helped me. I have linked in the properties of the project, but the project, when compiled, says

```
/home/(username)/NetBeansProjects/testGame_cpp/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
```

This is really irritating, and also, I noticed that when I set link options, they don't appear in the command that runs to build the project:

```
g++ -g -m64 -o testGame main.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic
```

Please help, this is agitating!! ;(

Here is all I have of the project (main.cpp):

```
/* 
* File:   main.cpp
* Author: toriyamo
*
* Created on November 27, 2015, 5:34 PM
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "**Failed to initialize glfw3!!**\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Also, if I comment out the if() statement, then it compiles with

```
BUILD SUCCESSSFUL (total time: 259ms)
```

**EDIT 2**: I don't believe I installed GLFW correctly... I downloaded it, built it with CMake, and it was successful. I typed into a terminal:

```
su
Password: (password)
make
```

This was the output:
http://pastebin.com/WMVGRAWp

Apparently it worked... but why is it that the glfw lib's won't work?

**EDIT 3**: I changed up the makefile so that it builds with options that were in the linking options. I got a new error:
http://pastebin.com/aHuZ1jsg
Must be missing X- something...

**EDIT 4 (the final one)**: ***See answer below!!!***

Comment: Try adding: `-lglfw -lGL -lGLU`

Comment: I already have that. In the exact order.

Comment: They are not in the list of options passed to `g++`, so then maybe they are not inputted in the right field. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040303/how-to-link-libs-in-netbeans-linux

Comment: I just keep getting error after error after error...
This is how it goes:

I get the first error.
I get an error trying to fix that error.
I get an error trying to fix the error for the fix to the original error.

Also, please read the [EDITS] in the post for any updates. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @MisaLazovic Please try to improve as much of a post as you can when suggesting edits instead of merely adding/removing tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @codeMagic OK, noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... of course only after I post the question lol.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685903/glfw3-undefined-reference-to-xrr) page, and typed in this command:

```
sudo find / | grep "glfw3\.pc"
cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
```

I then found

```
Requires.private:  x11 xrandr xinerama xi xxf86vm xcursor gl
```

I added the options in this that I didn't have before into the makefile, and it worked! Finally! Torment of ***errors*** ended!!

Anyways, hope it helps other people as well!!